# Clustered INdex in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have been asked the following question in an interview recently.
Using clustered index in a table, which operation among insert, delete or update will be faster or slower?

Comment: And what did you answer?

Comment: To some extent, it depends on what the clustered index is on - is it on real data column(s) or on an identity column?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever,can you please explain more ?you mean in case of identity there is no page split .please explain.

Comment: Indexes are created to enhance DQL querie (SELECT) and it has negative effect on DML (Insert, Delete and Update). If they did not give any real time scenario, I would say all the DML queries will have negative effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effect of indexes on DML queries is mostly negative ie more are the number of indexes created on table , slower is performance of an DML query like insert , update ,delete.

In fact , removing indexes while doing bulk load i.e inserting huge number of rows at same time is common practice.
[See here](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/dml)